# How to get the $T1$ specs for the Rigetti's quantum processor (Aspen 7)

Tags: simulation, rigetti, pyquil

I am trying to find the $T1$ coherence time for different qubits of Rigetti's quantum processor (Aspen 7) using Python. I tried using `Specs()` but encountered an error.

Comment: Hi, could you share what error message you got?